# gcm.jar to FCM migration questions

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on a project which uses the long out of date gcm.jar (v 1.0.2, pre `InstanceID`) for google cloud messaging push notification support. I want to update to the new Firebase Cloud messaging platform but have some questions about doing so because the [google documentation about transitioning](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm) is about transitioning from the newer `instanceID` based version of GCM (v 3.0).

Does importing the gcm project in the console invalidate the current API key? I don't want to break notifications for existing users if I have to update the api key used on the server side.

I know that the transition from `instanceID` GCM to FCM doesn't require any server changes. Will I need to change my server/database implementation for registration tokens? (Do pre-instanceID tokens have the same format as the current tokens?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing the project into the Firebase console *shouldn't* invalidate the current key but it was a bug in the past so that's something to be aware of when doing the migration.

Pre-instance ID tokens are shorter than the InstanceID based tokens.